# Status : Debugger Session # 0 active

Tags: react-native, expo, chrome-remote-debugging

I am not able to find my files to debug when running the expo app on real android device through expo. How do I debug my app remotely ?
RN version: 0.54
Expo SDK version: 30
React Version: "16.3.1"
Kindly see the following image url to understand the problem

[image: debugger screenshot]

Comment: The files were present along with the **node_modules** could track them there